# Symfony \ Component \ ErrorHandler \ Error \ FatalError

Tags: php, laravel

The actual error:

```
During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::offsetExists($offset)
should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice
in /home/u117697797/domains/divafashion.in/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1658
```

The stacktrace from laravel.log:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/u117697797/domains/divafashion.in/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(23): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/u117697797/domains/divafashion.in/public_html/core/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('/home/u11769779...')
#2 /home/u117697797/domains/divafashion.in/public_html/core/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile() #3 /home/u117697797/domains/divafashion.in/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseServiceProvider.php(42): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#4 /home/u117697797/domains/divafashion.in/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(627): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider->register()
#5 public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
**/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php23**
13. use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
14. use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Concerns\AsPivot;
15. use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;
16. use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
17. use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
18. use Illuminate\Support\Collection as BaseCollection;
19. use Illuminate\Support\Str;
20. use Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls;
21. use JsonSerializable;
22.  
23. abstract class Model implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess, Jsonable, JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable
24. {
25.    use Concerns\HasAttributes,
26.        Concerns\HasEvents,
27.        Concerns\HasGlobalScopes,
28.        Concerns\HasRelationships,
29.        Concerns\HasTimestamps,
30.        Concerns\HidesAttributes,
31.        Concerns\GuardsAttributes,
32.        ForwardsCalls;
```

What I want:

I want to live my website without 500 HTTP error or this error. Can you help me?

Comment: Ok, can you paste your laravel.log again in your original question? This one is too unreadable to make any sense. Do *not* change sourcecode inside the *vendor* folder, it will become a big mess

Comment: all informations are vendor codes, pls pase your code (route,controller, model)